# How to remove a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that extends DialogFragment in Activity. I show it when click on a button:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 ft.add(TabsFragment.newInstance(), "Fragment");
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.commit();
```

And in *onDismiss* method in Fragment, I remove it at this way:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

So, My problem is, When I twice click on button fast, Two fragments show up. I replace these codes to Activity:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
    ft.add(TabsFragment.newInstance(), "Fragment");
    ft.addToBackStack("Tabs");
    ft.commit();
}
```

But at this way, Fragment displayed only once. When I click on button *getBackStackEntryCount* is 0 and fragment show up. When fragment dissmissed and click on button again, *getBackStackEntryCount* is 1, Although I remove fragment in *onDismiss* method. Is any another way to remove fragment and low-off *getBackStackEntryCount*?

Comment: I think better way is to restrict fast clicking on button. Because the core problem is not in the fragment removing, as I think.

Comment: @OlegSkidan I can use a handler and etc, but I think this way is dirty!

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment1);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: with use `hide()` method, fragment not destroyed and it causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you don't want to do it dirty, then...
1. Use popular libs, like rx. Because it is more clear way to write your code.

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.12'
```

2. Use https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding It helps you to work with your views more comfortable.

An example:

```
RxView.clicks(yourButton)
            .throttleFirst(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe (click -> {your code})
```

Where RxView.clicks - is your onClickListener,
.throttleFirst - is your delay
.subscribe  - is your click action

You can do it better. Just wrap some parts in methods =)

Edit. Why is it better way? Because it helps to solve the core problem (rapid clicks). It doesn't help to solve aftermath.

Comment: I would not throttle the first click. It could be the case that the second click comes out of a slow spawn of the fragment, when the user thinks that he might not have clicked it properly. I would disable the button after the first click until the fragment shows up.

Comment: Don't you want to show progress bar while fragment is in creation/loading phase?

Comment: I use `bottomNavigationView` and my button is an item of it. How I can handler `onNavigationItemSelected` with this library?